# How to access child element in parent element

Tags: polymer-2.x

I am creating a element in which parent element is having a button. On tap of this button the properties of child element are changing. Following is the code snippet-

```
<parent-element>
     <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{aa}}">
    <child-element id="aa{{index}}">
    <button on-tap="_clickFunction">
    </template>

_ClickFunction(){
            for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){           
               this.shadowRoot.querySelector("aa" + i).prop1 = true;
               this.shadowRoot.querySelector("aa" + i).prop2 = true;
            }
}
</parent-element>


<child-element>
    properties:{
        prop1: Boolean,
        prop2: Boolean,
}
</child-element>
```

How does it possible without using id or any dom-manipulation.
if there is dom-repeat, how to access properties of particular child element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
_ClickFunction(e){
    let childItemIndex = e.model.index;
    var childItem = this.shadowRoot.getElementById(`aa${childItemIndex}`);
    item.prop1 = !!1;
    item.prop2 = !!1;
}
```